# Show the content of a schedule in a gridview without exporting the schedule

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

The problem is following:
I am working in on my project and now I would like to upload the schedule automatically to my database, without needing to export my schedule.
The user should simply select the schedule ant the data in it should be uploaded. 
 I am already able to upload data from a gridview/datatable to my database. Now all i need is a way to get the data from a schedule into a gridview/datatable 
 Does anybody have a idea on how i can do that? The api-documentation was not much help (I am working with C# and revit 2018.2)
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily access Schedule data without exporting. Firstly, get all the schedules and read the data cell by cell. Secondly, create dictionary and store data in form of key, value pairs. Now you can use the schedule data as you want. I have tried this in Revit 2019.

Here is the implementation

```
public void getScheduleData(Document doc)
{
    FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
    IList<Element> collection = collector.OfClass(typeof(ViewSchedule)).ToElements();

    String prompt = "ScheduleData :";
    prompt += Environment.NewLine;

    foreach (Element e in collection)
    {
        ViewSchedule viewSchedule = e as ViewSchedule;
        TableData table = viewSchedule.GetTableData();
        TableSectionData section = table.GetSectionData(SectionType.Body);
        int nRows = section.NumberOfRows;
        int nColumns = section.NumberOfColumns;

        if (nRows > 1)
        {
            //valueData.Add(viewSchedule.Name);

            List<List<string>> scheduleData = new List<List<string>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
            {
                List<string> rowData = new List<string>();

                for (int j = 0; j < nColumns; j++)
                {
                    rowData.Add(viewSchedule.GetCellText(SectionType.Body, i, j));
                }
                scheduleData.Add(rowData);
            }

            List<string> columnData = scheduleData[0];
            scheduleData.RemoveAt(0);

            DataMapping(columnData, scheduleData);
        }
    }
}

public static void DataMapping(List<string> keyData, List<List<string>>valueData)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> items= new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    string prompt = "Key/Value";
    prompt += Environment.NewLine;

    foreach (List<string> list in valueData)
    {
        for (int key=0, value =0 ; key< keyData.Count && value< list.Count; key++,value++)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> newItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string k = keyData[key];
            string v = list[value];
            newItem.Add(k, v);
            items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }

    foreach (Dictionary<string, string> item in items)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in item)
        {
            prompt += "Key: " + kvp.Key + ",Value: " + kvp.Value;
            prompt += Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    Autodesk.Revit.UI.TaskDialog.Show("Revit", prompt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Building Coder](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) answers that exact question in full describing how to use the [Schedule API to access schedule data](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/05/the-schedule-api-and-access-to-schedule-data.html).